# How to have a function returning 1 value in some circumstances return 2 or 3 values and vice-versa?

Tags: swift, function

I'm new to Swift. Is it possible to have a function return by standard only 1 value and in some circumstances 2 or 3 values ?

Comment: Consider returning a tuple or array?

Comment: I have already a function which returns a result. I have just found out now that for a certain case I need to return 2 results from this function. So I constructed an if statement and so on but in the end I can only return 1 value. For 99% of the other cases I just need 1 result.

Comment: Sounds like a tuple would do what you need. Consider posting some code to illustrate the issue?

Comment: As @CollinD said consider using tuple...You can use tuple with nil values as well.For reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489647/is-it-possible-to-have-a-nil-value-in-a-tuple-with-swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a tuple:

```
func functionThatReturnsTuple(numberOfElementsToReturn: Int) -> (String?, Int?) {
    if numberOfElementsToReturn == 1 {
        return ("One", nil)
    }
    if numberOfElementsToReturn == 2 {
        return ("One", 2)
    }
    return (nil, nil)
}
```

You can return array:

```
func functionThatReturnsArray(numberOfElementsToReturn: Int) -> [String] {

    if numberOfElementsToReturn == 3 {
        return ["One", "Two", "Three"]
    }
    ....
    return []
}
```

Notice that both examples use optionals, make sure to handle them .

Comment: I went for the tuple variant and I'm using the first number of the tuple as a standard result and the second one as nil, being an optional. All working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use enum:

```
enum Value<A, B, C> {
    case single(A)
    case pair(A, B)
    case triplet(A, B, C)
}

func yourFunc<A, B, C>(numberOfParameters: Int) -> Value<A, B, C> {
   // determine how many params you need to return, and return them
}
```

And inn your `outer` code just check `Value`'s case with `switch` of `if case`.